# joint density of two sums of independent random var with common component

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Suppose we have three iid draws from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Call these random variables $A, B$ and $C$.
Let $X=A+B$ and $Y=B+C$.
I have figured out that the density of $X$ (or $Y$) is
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
x &\mbox{ if }  x \in [0,1] \\
2-x &\mbox{ if } x \in (1,2].
\end{cases}$$
I can also see that $X=A+Y-C$.
However, I  am still struggling with the joint density of $X,Y$ and the conditional density of $X|Y$ and the corresponding CDFs. I am looking forward to hints!

Let me show you what I have tried and where I want to get at.
Similar to $f_X$ above, I used convolution to obtain
$$f_{Y|X} (y\,;\, x) = \begin{cases}
1+y-x &\mbox{ if }  y \in [x-1,x] \\
1-y+x &\mbox{ if } y \in (x,x+1].
\end{cases}$$
The joint density then should just be $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_{Y|X}(y\,;\, x)$.

My book suggests that the joint density looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5g5X.png) and also that
$\frac{f_{Y|X}(y\,;\, x)}{F_{Y|X}(y\,;\, x)}= \frac{2}y$. Neither coincides with what I have done. Can anyone help?

Comment: Since I am very certain about my marginal density and I suppose the book's joint density is correct, I assume my conditional density appears to be incorrect. I obtained it from the marginal density of $(A-C), f_{A-C}$ and I plugged in $f_{A-C}(y-x)$.
If you don't like my concrete example, I would be very happy for a general approach to determine the joint density of random variables $X,Y$ with $X= g(A,B)$ and $Y=g(C,B)$ with independent draws $A,B,C$ and some function $g$.

Comment: "... and also that $\frac{f(x|x)}{F(x|x)}= $" What on earth does that $f(x|x)$ mean? TYpo?

Comment: Yes, a typo. I apoligize. I edited it. It is supposed to be the conditional density over the conditional CDF evaluated at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same method used to find the marginal.

$$\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\int_0^1 f_{A,B,C}(x-b,b,y-b)~\mathrm d b
\\[2ex]&=\int_{\max\{0,x-1,y-1\}}^{\min\{1,x,y\}}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 2,\max\{0,x-1\}\leqslant y\leqslant\min\{2,x+1\}}\mathrm d b
\\[2ex]&\ddots
\end{align}$$